# LL command on Centos

Tags: centos, file-permissions

What does the column "mysql" mean in a line listed by 'll' command:

ll Downloads/
total 1580272
-rw-r-----.  1 mysql   abigail     68096 Oct 25 15:22 6 test.doc

I don't know why and when "abigail" was changed to "mysql" for the directory "Downloads"? Because of that, I can't download file to the default "Downloads" directory when I logged in as the user "abigail". How to change "mysql" back to "abigail"? Thanks.

I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql is the username there and abigail is the groupname for usergroup

```
-rw-r--r--    1 username    groupname        0 Apr 11 00:09 fish
-rw-r--r--    1 username    groupname       11 Apr 11 00:10 hello.txt
```

Here is the command [wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Commands/File_System_Utilities)

Comment: But I logged in as "abigail", not "mysql".

Comment: Hey @martin you may be right buddy but i give you link of commands and if you want to change owner you can use chown